# Which is the correct container for a search input? Span or Div?

Tags: html, css, semantics

According [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) `span`'s permitted content is `Phrasing content` and `div` is `Flow content`.

I was looking at the html generated source of Facebook and I noticed they wrapped the "find friends" main search input in a `span` and marked it `display:block`. To me this seems ridiculous since a `div` is a block level element and a `span` is inline.

And according to MDN:

> `<span>` is very much like a `<div>` element, but `<div>` is a block-level element whereas a `<span>` is an inline element.

Why didn't they just use a div? Is a `span` a better choice because it is for phrasing content? Or maybe it was just not a big deal to them?

Is there any reason that one should wrap a search `input` in a `span` vs a `div`?

Comment: And what element is that span wrapped in? A div is not "a span with `display: block`". HTML and CSS are two separate things entirely. A div is a div and a span is a span - the only thing they have in common is that they are nonsemantic.

Comment: @BoltClock from MDN "<span> is very much like a <div> element, but <div> is a block-level element whereas a <span> is an inline element." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span. It is wrapped in a div.

Comment: That's just an oversimplification and, IIRC, a holdover from HTML 4. As you've already stated, a span is phrasing content and a div is flow content. Making a span `display: block` doesn't change the fact that the span is phrasing content (and likewise for making a div `display: inline`). Again I ask, what element is the span wrapped in? Because a span doesn't mean anything on its own.

Comment: but is a search input flow content? Or is the big issue that the span was set to block?

Comment: @BoltClock as I stated above. It is wrapped in a div.  And as charlietfl asks. Is a search input flow content?

Comment: @charlietfl Is a search input flow content? So a span is ok set to block as long as it contains flow content?

Comment: seems like a pretty trivial issue to me ... passes validation, doesn't affect aria, has no cross browser display issues. Not even sure what the context of this question is...theoretical or real world problem

Comment: I missed that, sorry. I don't know if Facebook is a good model of semantic markup. The spec says an input can be used in contexts where phrasing content is expected - and most places that accept flow content also accept phrasing content.

Comment: if it wasn't for out of spec concepts...lots of what we do now would never have been done ... `<script style="display:block">read my code</script>`

Answer (score 0):

The type of a content is decided by the arrangement of it in the page - not by the type of CSS used on it.

This particular span is used inside a `<div>` element with no siblings. This gives a clear idea about the type of content it is used as.

Using a `display: block` in such an arrangement seems very legitimate.